# What does "Washington panics at U2 shots of Cuban-style latrines" mean?

Tags: latin-america

In Bruce Cockburn's song ["Nicaragua"](https://youtu.be/t1iwJOYTSTw?t=185) (1984), he sings, awkwardly fitting a few extra syllables into his line,

> Sandino of the shining dream
> Who stood up to the US Marines
> **Now Washington panics at U2 shots of Cuban-style latrines**
> They peek from planes
> Eavesdrop from ships
> Voyeurs licking moistened lips

To what is this line a reference? Googling it just turns up this song. But it's obviously some kind of event. Did the band U2 take some photos of something? What are Cuban-style latrines? Why did they cause Washington to panic? I'm beyond my depth in Latin American history.

--

(Update)

Thanks, all — this has gone a long way to clarifying it. The meaning of the sentence is now mostly clear: given that the Cuban missile crisis was prompted by U-2 aircraft photography revealing missile sites, and that Cuba was aiding the Sandinistas, evidence of the same kind in Nicaragua would be of concern to Washington. I'm still slightly fuzzy on whether photos of latrines can be or were ever mistaken for photos of missile sites or whether it's a tongue-in-cheek reference to the JFK briefing Jan linked to.

And, once the meaning has been clarified, it remains to be found whether there was a specific shot in Nicaragua that — to take the logic to its conclusion — caused the US to think Nicaragua might also be preparing missiles. (Another option is that the line is a reference to the Cuban missile crisis itself, but that seems far enough removed from the time and place of Nicaragua, and also validated by history, that the line would be out of place.) Sadly the U-2 Wiki article's section on its operational history doesn't say anything about Nicaragua.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but the "U2" is probably a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_U-2 spy plane, taking pictures of Cuba for the CIA or other agency. Digging a hole in the ground can mean all kinds of things... maybe it's the early stage of a missile silo. Or maybe someone had to take a dump. I don't know the specific event referred to though.

Comment: Most likely it’s a reference to the U2 reconnaissance aircraft that did take an important part in the Cuban crisis. Perhaps you can find a hint in the English Wiki page, operational history section is quite extensive

Comment: For years I thought U2, the band, was named from U2, the airplane.  Yes, yes, I am reeaaally slow, I know, but their first album's New Years Day video was WW2-Russia styled, so I have a semi-excuse.

Comment: One might think that the latrines part is about cesspits. After all cesspits can be several meters deep, more than a meter in circumference, and circular (the construction of a simple latrine if you already have a cesspit is left as an exercise to the reader). But it turns out it might be about something else: https://foreignpolicy.com/2012/10/18/why-is-a-missile-site-like-a-latrine/

Comment: "Cuban-style latrines" is a jokey reference to the idea that the US was convinced the Sandinistas were a Cuba-backed plot and desperately looking for evidence where none existed. Historically accurate or not, that's the authors intent here I think. A connection did exist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_assistance_to_the_Sandinista_National_Liberation_Front

Comment: @BrianZ - The sudden appearance of Cuban-style ... er ... mundane architecture does seem like a pretty strong indication of a coherent Cuban presence.